# SharePoint not sending email to one user

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, exchange

SharePoint is not sending emails to one user.  I have checked the permissions of the user in both SharePoint and exchange, the only difference I can find is that sharepoint is showing a different email than the users main email.
I have made the SharePoint email an alias of the users email and the user is still not receiving any SharePoint emails.  When the user was originally onboarded, their accounts were created incorrectly with the wrong email address as the main address used.
After the remake of their accounts, the correct email was used and a sync performed but SharePoint is still showing the incorrect email address.  I set the old email as an alias of the new email and they are still not receiving emails from SharePoint.  Is there a way to make it so that the user can receive emails from SharePoint?  What am I missing?
We are using SharePoint online with an O365 E3 license